# Android 6.0 - Set video speed with PlaybackParams

Tags: java, android, video, android-mediaplayer, video-processing

I have problems about how to implement [**PlaybackParams**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/PlaybackParams.html) to set video speed:

> `public PlaybackParams getPlaybackParams ()`
>
> Added in API level 23 
>    Gets the playback rate using PlaybackParams.

```
PlaybackParams setSpeed (float speed) //Sets the speed factor.
```

> **Returns**: 
>   the playback rate being used. 
>   **Throws IllegalStateException**: 
>   if the internal sync engine or the audio track has not been initialized.

This is my code:

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
    {
        mp.setPlaybackParams(new PlaybackParams().setSpeed(1.f));

        if (mPlaybackState == PlaybackState.PLAYING) { mVideoView.start();}
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Does speed setting of `1.f` work properly (since **1.0** is normal speed) or you get error message? Try : `mp.setPlaybackParams(new PlaybackParams().setSpeed(2.5));` What happens...?

Answer (score 4):

You are getting an IllegalStateException while calling the 'setPlayParams' method, because you're not doing PlaybackParams params = mp.getPlaybackParams(), set the speed and then pass it to mp.setPlaybackParams()! Set the speed DIRECTLY while calling the mp.getPlayParams()!

```
MediaPlayer mp = ...; 
float speed = 0.55f;     
mp.setPlaybackParams(mp.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(speed));
```

Answer (score 2):

After many try i find a solution.

**Example** how use **VideoView**

```
final VideoView mVideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
mVideoView.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/bluetooth/test.webm"); //Path of your file video
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        mp.setPlaybackParams(mp.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(0.55f));
        mVideoView.start();
    }
});
MediaController media = new MediaController(this); //this is for play and restart play manually
media.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
mVideoView.setMediaController(media);
//mVideoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not started the Media Playe..

Try This Code:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
{
    mp.start()
    mp.setPlaybackParams(new PlaybackParams().setSpeed(1.f));

  
}
```